# react-dropdown-tree component: Use ellipsis to prevent line break

Tags: react-dropdown-tree-select

I would like to prevent the component from expanding vertically as more items are selected. If some items do not fit into the row, I would like to have "..." signaling the user that further items were selected.

The following example achieves this behaviour for react-select:
https://codesandbox.io/s/v638kx67w7?file=/index.js:1219-1231

What is the best way to do this with react-dropdown-tree?